# can anyone help me to clear the error occured in uber api

Tags: uber-api

after authorizing the app in python the auth_url is showing invalid scope after getting the url

> auth_flow
>   =AuthorizationCodeGrant("Ws4Za7kSxIdQdpxcZnL2WC9L8NVl3UBT","all_trips delivery history history_lite places profile request request_receipt
>   ride_widgets","qccwQVFYdzSIFwD86DIYAJeBB-Wg8KBuXO0mWiNN","http://127.0.0.1/")
>
> http://127.0.0.1/?error=invalid_scope&state=WD7kEksCoCsUap219zzge18MuoxV6bvS#_

Comment: What happens if you try just one scope like 'history' (and uncheck all the other scopes, including the privileged scopes like 'request')?

Answer (score 1):

You are not passing the scopes properly, your scope list looks like following after AuthorizationCodeGrant is executed:

scope=a+l+l+*+t+r+i+p+s+++d+e+l+i+v+e+r+y+++h+i+s+t+o+r+y+++h+i+s+t+o+r+y+*+l+i+t+e+++p+l+a+c+e+s+++p+r+o+f+i+l+e+++r+e+q+u+e+s+t+++r+e+q+u+e+s+t+*+r+e+c+e+i+p+t+++r+i+d+e+*+w+i+d+g+e+t+s&state=0kFxqT7cTka4pbkbdAObpSzrh8mF4pUR&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2F127.0.0.1%2F&response_type=code&client_id=Ws4Za7kSxIdQdpxcZnL2WC9L8NVl3UBT

So you will need to do something like this:

> auth_flow = AuthorizationCodeGrant(
>           'XXX',
>           {'all_trips ', 'delivery', 'history', 'history_lite', 'places', 'profile', 'request', 'request_receipt', 'ride_widgets'},
>           'XXX',
>           'http://localhost'
>       )